# Вывести число в значении тега input при рендеринге шаблона django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть django шаблон с тегом input

```
  <input
      type="number"
      step="any"
      class="form-control"
      id="raw_longitude"
      placeholder="Долгота"
      name="raw_longitude"
      value={{ rival_entry.raw_longitude }}
 />
```

При рендеринге в контекст передаю объект модели **rival_entry** с полем **raw_longitude**.
Тип в поле Decimal.
Но фактически значение не отображается. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя, как видно из инспектора, значение присутствует.

Comment: замените в {{ rival_entry.raw_longitude }} запятую на точку

Comment: @stxdtm каким образом?

Comment: каким образом форматнуть значение чтобы его принял тег input?

Comment: @andreymal, это стеб?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В значении input type=number допускается только точка в качестве разделителя в числе. Django выводит запятую, потому что следует настройкам локализации: в России принято ставить запятую — вот Django и ставит. Очевидно, здесь это не нужно (браузер сам заменит точку на запятую, когда будет рисовать инпут на экране), и у шаблонизатора Django есть фильтр `unlocalize` на такой случай, позволяющий проигнорировать настройки локализации и вывести точку:

```
{% load l10n %}

<input type="number" value="{{ rival_entry.raw_longitude|unlocalize }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделай так, т.е. возьми в кавычки

```
<input
      type="number"
      step="any"
      class="form-control"
      id="raw_longitude"
      placeholder="Долгота"
      name="raw_longitude"
      value="{{ rival_entry.raw_longitude }}"
 />
```

Comment: Пробовалл по всякому и так тоже. не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с фильтром тоже мне пришел на ум.
Вот мой вариант.

```
def to_float_digits(value: decimal.Decimal) -> str:
    """
        фильтр представления вещественного числа.
    """
    value = float(value)
    return repr(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В Javascript разделителем в вещественных числах служит точка;
2. тег `input` c `type="number"` игнорирует все значения, которые не являются числами;

Исходя из этих двух предпосылок, вариантов решения проблемы так же два:

1. не использовать `type="number"`, если в этом нет явной необходимости (используйте `type="text"`);
2. Заменить в переменной `rival_entry.raw_longitude` запятую на точку, чтобы она воспринималась JS как вещественное число (например, можно заменить непосредственно в функции, которая передает данные в шаблон, либо написать свой фильтр и использовать его прямо в шаблоне);

Пример с созданием собственного фильтра для шаблона:

1. в папке с проектом создаем папку `templatetags`;
2. в ней создаем пустой файл `__init__.py` и файл, в котором будет находиться наш фильтр (например, `myfilter.py`);
3. в `myfilter.py` пишем следующее:

   ```
   from django import template

   register = template.Library()

   @register.filter
   def myreplace(data_string):
     return data_string.replace(",", ".")
   ```
4. загружаем фильтр в шаблоне с помощью конструкции

   ```
   {% load myfilter %}
   ```

   обратите внимание - название должно совпадать с названием файла, созданного в п.2;
5. затем стандартным способом применяем фильтр к переменной:

   ```
   {{ rival_entry.raw_longitude | myreplace }}
   ```

   фильтр называется так же, как функция, объявленная в п.3 после `@register.filter`

Comment: Как именно заменить запятую на точку-то? Нет, это не стеб, если вы знаете - расскажите, чего скрывать-то :)

Comment: @andreymal, добавил пример в ответ

Comment: только вот беда, ваш код не заработает, потому что Decimal не имеет метода `replace` ;) (Ну что за дела, пришлось самому ответ писать...)

Comment: @andreymal, хм. на этот момент не обратил внимания) я обычно храню координаты в поле с типом geometry (postgis):) Ну, может кому другому пригодится... Хотя в питоне вещественные числа вроде тоже через точку записываются, так что не все так однозначно..